# CiviCRM Dasboard Disappeared

Tags: wordpress, dashboard, menu

Since updating to WordPress 5.5, my CiviCRM dashboard is gone and the "Configure Dashboard" link does nothing. Also, all of my menu bars are gone. My data still seems to be there, but the top bar menus to access and manipulate them are gone. [image]
Is this a common issue, or has something gotten screwed up in translation?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding below lines into end of civicrm.settings.php file

```
global $civicrm_paths;
$civicrm_paths['civicrm.root']['path'] = '/path-to-wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/';
$civicrm_paths['civicrm.root']['url'] = 'http://sitename.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/';
```

Comment: When I add that code, I get a critical error message.

Comment: did you replace the path-to-wordpress to your wordpress path?

Comment: Yes, although I might be doing the 'path' wrong. Should that be the same as the 'url' or where should that one start?

Comment: Replace the site name with your domain name.   Path you copy paste the civicrm_root variable from civicrm.settings.php

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was because I added an SSL certificate to my site, and had to go in and change every "http://" to "https://" in the civicrm.settings.php file.
Problem solved. Thank you for your help!